# Android CheckedTextView how to get choiceIndicator default drawable name?

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources

Someone knows what is the name default  `Drawables` using in `android.R.attr.listChoi‌​ceIndicatorMultiple` and `android.R.attr.listChoi‌​ceIndicatorSingle?`

I would like programatically switch between modes unsing original resouces drawable.

is not possible using this way:

```
view.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.attr.listChoi‌​ceIndicatorMultiple);
```

So i'm trying to figure out the real **drawable** name referenced by `android.R.attr.listChoi‌​ceIndicatorMultiple`

Comment: you mean something like "android getting attribute value" resutls in google search?

Comment: @Selvin, you know something about how use run time Attr? Are you already tried do something like it? So, yes! I've researched by myself before open a question, i tried inspect the component default styleable and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found inside appCompat the following resources:

```
   static int checkMaterial = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_btn_check_material;
   static int radioMaterial = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material;
```

And it works fine!

**Edited**

The better solution:

```
ViewHolder holder;...

TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme =  holder.textView.getContext().getTheme();
int checkMarkDrawableResId;

if (isMultiSelectionEnabled) {

    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple, value, true);
    int checkMarkDrawableResId = value.resourceId;

} else {

    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle, value, true);
    int checkMarkDrawableResId = value.resourceId;
}

holder.textView.setCheckMarkDrawable(checkMarkDrawableResId);
```